# VBA - Success and Error handling for stored procedure on SQL Server with ADO

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado

I have a stored procedure `HS.spInsertStudentNote` in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [HS].[spInsertStudentNote]
    (@StudentID INT,
     @Note VARCHAR(MAX),
     @UserID VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO HS.STUDENT_NOTE (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NOTE, CREATED_USERID, CREATED_TIMESTAMP)
    VALUES (@StudentID, @Note, @UserID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END
GO
```

I am calling this stored procedure when a user clicks on a button in an Access form and it successfully stores the note in my database:

```vb
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum
cn.Open getDBConnectionString

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "HS.spInsertStudentNote"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@StudentID", adBigInt, adParamInput, , lStudentID)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Note", adLongVarWChar, adParamInput, -1, Me.inputNote.Value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@UserID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, (Environ$("Username")))
    .Execute
End With
```

I would like to be able to handle any potential errors resulting from the execution of this stored procedure, and also any success (ex: If successful, close the form, refresh another form, etc.).

As an example, if I use lStudentID = 999999 and execute the Stored Procedure, I am getting a Microsoft Visual Basic pop up with *Run-time error -2147217900 - The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY Constraint ...* since STUDENT_ID = 999999 does not exist in the database.

Would it be possible to capture this error code in the VBA code before it is shown to the user as a Microsoft Visual Basic Error Popup? I would like to split the results as "Success" and "Error" and for "Error", have a Case statement that would target specific returned code.

On a side note, my code does not actually allows users to store a student note for a STUDENT_ID that does not exist in my database. I am strictly using this scenario as an example to build on, for other possible scenarios where a stored procedure could also return an error.

Comment: Of course you can trap the error. Just google error handling in Access. There are thousands and thousands, if not millions, of examples.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm